# Pandas check for future condition by group

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to flag each row by whether a condition will occur at a future date in the data. Whether this condition has occurred in the past is irrelevant. Moreover, I'm trying to perform this labeling by group.

An intuitive way to think about this is whether someone will buy pants at a future date.

```
id      date        item
1    2000-01-01     'foo'
1    2000-01-02     'pants'
1    2000-01-03     'bar'
2    2000-01-02     'organ'
2    2000-02-01     'beef'
3    2000-01-01     'pants'
3    2000-01-10     'oranges'
3    2000-02-20     'pants'
```

Would in turn become:

```
id      date        item      will_buy_pants
1    2000-01-01     'foo'          1
1    2000-01-02     'pants'        0
1    2000-01-03     'bar'          0
2    2000-01-02     'organ'        0
2    2000-02-01     'beef'         0
3    2000-01-01     'pants'        1
3    2000-01-10     'oranges'      1
3    2000-02-20     'pants'        0
```

Edit:
This is not a prediction problem. Whether someone will buy pants is already expressed in the data. I just want a flag on each row.

Comment: do you want to assign randomly `0` and `1`? ;) do you have any prediction algorithm ?

Comment: @MaxU seems like if "item" column has "pants" on a subsequent index, 1. Start over when you see pants. The last one should be zero though.

Comment: @ayhan, i'm not sure...  so let's wait until it'll be clear or someone will guess what OP really wants;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """id      date        item
1    2000-01-01     'foo'
1    2000-01-02     'pants'
1    2000-01-03     'bar'
2    2000-01-02     'organ'
2    2000-02-01     'beef'
3    2000-01-01     'pants'
3    2000-01-10     'oranges'
3    2000-02-20     'pants'"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[1])
```

#### Solution

I'm using nested `apply`

```
def check_future_pants(x, df):
    date_condition = x.date < df.date
    pant_condition = df.item == "'pants'"
    return (date_condition & pant_condition).any()

def check_df_pants(df):
    return df.apply(lambda x: check_future_pants(x, df), axis=1)

df['will_buy_pants'] = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(check_df_pants)
```

#### Demonstration / Explanation

```
# Let's start with a sub-group
df1 = df[df.id == 1].copy()

print df1.apply(lambda x: check_future_pants(x, df1), axis=1)

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

This works for one group but the checking I do works on a `DataFrame` so I perform a nested `apply` with another checking function `check_df_pants`.

```
df['will_buy_pants'] = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(check_df_pants)
pring df

   id       date       item will_buy_pants
0   1 2000-01-01      'foo'           True
1   1 2000-01-02    'pants'          False
2   1 2000-01-03      'bar'          False
3   2 2000-01-02    'organ'          False
4   2 2000-02-01     'beef'          False
5   3 2000-01-01    'pants'           True
6   3 2000-01-10  'oranges'           True
7   3 2000-02-20    'pants'          False
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I apologize - very inattentive today. So this is working, does what you want I think and uses pandas groupby and apply.

First generate a second dataframe with two indices - item and id and the maximum date for each of these combinations:

```
gd = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['item','id'])['date'].max())
```

This is what this dataframe looks like:

```
In [5]: gd
Out[5]: 
                   date
item      id           
'bar'     1  2000-01-03
'beef'    2  2000-02-01
'foo'     1  2000-01-01
'oranges' 3  2000-01-10
'organ'   2  2000-01-02
'pants'   1  2000-01-02
          3  2000-02-20
```

Define a function checking if it is bought in the future, using groupby. It takes two arguments - the row of the dataframe and the grouped dataframe above. You can do grouping inside every function call or move it outside.

```
def check_pants(row,gd):
    if row.id in gd.loc["'pants'"].index.values and \
        row.date < gd.loc["'pants'",row.id].date:
            return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

What it does - gets all IDs which bought "pants" and checks the date. If the current date is less than the maximum date than assing "1", otherwise "0".

You can then use apply:

```
In [9]: df['will_buy_pants'] = df.apply(lambda row: check_pants(row,gd), axis=1)

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
   id       date       item  will_buy_pants
0   1 2000-01-01      'foo'               1
1   1 2000-01-02    'pants'               0
2   1 2000-01-03      'bar'               0
3   2 2000-01-02    'organ'               0
4   2 2000-02-01     'beef'               0
5   3 2000-01-01    'pants'               1
6   3 2000-01-10  'oranges'               1
7   3 2000-02-20    'pants'               0
```

Sorry it took me so many edits.

Comment: Sorry. I think my formulation was unclear. I just want to look to future rows to figure this out. I'm not using a classifier.

Comment: OK. In this case we are talking about the code in the function check_if_will_buy_pants. For example you can group by items and check for the numbers of rows, i.e. if > 1 than it was bought in the future. Would it work? I can change the function to reflect it.